# Shared objects and related elements

Tags: actionscript-3

If I'm attempting to create a file that takes information a user inputs using input fields, save them, and then load them again later after the file has been opened and an option selected, what sort of things would I need to most research? I know there's something called sharedObject I need to research. What else? I've been searching Google, but I'm not finding anything covering this particular aspect. Games do it, yes? So an application could do it as well, without using Flex, yes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to brush up on your google-fu. I came up with 169K results on how to do what you're asking here. Here are some tutorials:

http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2008/12/28/understanding-as3-shared-objects/

http://drawlogic.com/2008/01/10/howto-sharedobjects-for-local-storage-as3/

http://www.flashdaweb.com/2008/01/tutorial-actionscript-3-using-shared-objects-to-show-the-time-of-page-browsing/

Googled "using shared objects in AS3"

Here is an excerpt from one of the sites showing how easy this is:

```
package {
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.net.SharedObject;
    import flash.text.*;
    public class as3_shared_objects extends Sprite {
        var shared:SharedObject;
        public function as3_shared_objects() {
            shared = SharedObject.getLocal("reloaded");
            if (shared.data.visits==undefined) {
                shared.data.visits = 1;
            }
            else {
                shared.data.visits ++;
            }
            show_text(shared.data.visits);
            shared.close();
        }
        public function show_text(str) {
            var shared_text:TextField = new TextField();
            var format:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
            format.font = "Lucida Console";
            format.color = 0xffff00;
            shared_text.width = 300;
            shared_text.defaultTextFormat = format;
            shared_text.x = 25;
            shared_text.y = 15;
            addChild(shared_text);
            shared_text.appendText("You visited this page "+str+" times");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You know what makes me feel foolish? The fact I completely labeled my title incorrectly. I'm sorry about that.

I think I've phrased my question incorrectly, I know about the shared object, I was curious if there were other aspects I need to research. However, the more I think about it, the more I think this question is too open ended. So I'll close it and since you've given me three great sites the answer will go to you.

Comment: I corrected the title. That way if anyone else comes looking for something similar your post can help them as well. Again, thank you.

Comment: lol no problem, please know I wasn't meaning to sound rude in my answer was just being funny. :)

Comment: I figured ;) I didn't take any offense